# TeamViewer to record a 1-participant meeting, with screen capture, audio

Tags: audio-recording, screen-capture, teamviewer, camtasia

Has anyone worked out how to use [TeamViewer 9](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) to record a solo session, say a self-hosted "meeting" with no actual participants?  Similar to camtasia, I want to **record my screen, along with audio** in a movie file, for documentation purposes. Adding in video and whiteboarding could be massively useful.  A group I'm working with already uses TeamViewer, so recording meetings as well as (one-person) presentations with a single tool could be efficient for us.

[These instructions for recording](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-record-teamviewer-session/) seem only to work when I join a meeting hosted elsewhere, not when I'm hosting the meeting and there are no participants.

[These instructions for converting .TVS to .AVI](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-record-teamviewer-session/) seem helpful once I have already recorded a session.

Comment: I am pretty sure your attempting to use the wrong tool if you are trying to capture your screen.  There are far better tools for something like that.

Comment: Specifics, @Ramhound.  What far better tools?

Comment: There are tools designed specifically to record your desktop and audio instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do exactly that, by starting a meeting and log in in from my mobile, and started recording then. Without a participant you can not record a presenter.